# What is the electrical influence of a magnetic field on alternating currrent

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Assume we put a very strong permanent magnet close to an AC carrying wire.

What would the electrical effects on the wire be?

Would there be any impedence or extra resistence caused?

Could a permanent magnet cause a high ac current carrying cable to overheat?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It will vibrate so much, depending on the frequency of your AC.

Comment: What I were to restrict it from vibrating through a solid fixture? Would that then convert the mechanical effects into electrical effects?

Answer (score 0):

It is called the [Ettingshausen effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ettingshausen_effect). The magnetic field exerts a force $\mathbf J \times \mathbf B$ on the current that is perpendicular to both, and if the field is perpendicular to the wire then depending on the current's direction it will push the electrons towards one side of the wire or to the other. This push effectively narrows the channel in which the current flows and overall will increase the skin-effect resistance of the wire. Ettingshausen could measure the evolved temperature difference between the sides during a dc current measurement. The temperature difference is very small for most metals because of their very good thermal conductivity but it exists.

Comment: The Ettingshausen effect seems to be about DC current, which in steady state should not experience any net force, because the Hall effect means in steady state there is electrostatic field due to surface charge that eliminates the effect of magnetic force. So the described narrowing of channel for AC current needs different explanation, like in the theory of skin effect.

Comment: @JánLalinský I do not believe that the Ettingshausen effect itself is dissipative as the temperature difference is maintained in a dc mode, I have not seen resistance measurements either way. But as we switch the direction of the current the temperature differentials between the sides must be flipping and consequently be dissipative and to result in the increase of the effective ac resistance of the wire. Whether this really manifests itself in the actual narrowing of the conducting channel I do not know but from the outside it will appear to increase the skin resistance.

Comment: @JánLalinský I also think that there is another way to look at this. The actual switching of the current direction will surely increase the path length of conducting charges as they drift back and forth because of the transversal Lorentz force as they move along the wire. Many years ago I was involved in some planar RF inductor work and its behavior was surprisingly complicated, in other words all theoretical and numerical predictions failed to predict the losses ...

Comment: Given how restricted electrons flow in a cable, compared to the whole cable moving through air as one, the internal vibration of the current in a fixed wire going from one side to the other would be much smaller in amplitude then the vibrations of a loose wire as one, right? I am also wondering if the concept of an eddy current break applies to this problem and might be bigger effect.